# WP::is_main_query() Not Working

Tags: plugins, posts

I am Trying to add some content before the posts container I use this code

```
add_action( 'wp', 'mainFunc' );
function mainFunc( $query ) {
    if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query()) {
        add_action("loop_start","anotherFunc");
    }
}
```

and I have anotherFunc() too.

but I get

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method WP::is_main_query() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wp\wp-content\plugins\topMessage\topmessage.php on
>   line 40

Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong hook, because what gets passed to [`wp`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-wp.php#L633) is the

> Current WordPress environment instance

not

> The WP_Query instance

like it is e.g. passed to [`loop_start`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/query.php#L3743).

You could actually just do your check inside the function callback you hook to `loop_start`.

Edit/note:

You could just have done `global $wp_query;` inside the `wp` hook, it is actually the first one where access to `$wp_query` is possible, to have access to it - not that I recommend doing it though. A better place - or at least the one I probably would go for - to hook into is the [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action, which does get passed `$query` - the `WP_Query` object - by reference.

Comment: " You could actually just do your check inside the function callback you hook to loop_start. " Can you Explain More ?

Comment: Put `if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {//code}` check in »anotherFunc()« instead. @ZeroBurnner

Comment: What a professional Idea .... ty Solved ...